# Will there be an Ubuntu One sync extension for the Opera browser?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, contacts, opera

Since Opera now support extensions and I use it for my daily use (great integration of Torrent downloader, browser and mail application), will there be an extension or is there any instructions on how to sync clients with Opera and Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently have plans to bring contacts sync to Opera, but if someone is interested in building an extension to do that I am happy to provide all the Ubuntu One information that would be needed to do so! If you, or someone you find, wants to make Opera a better citizen on the Ubuntu desktop, that'd be really cool.

Comment: I've been interested in creating an extension for a while and it would be great to find a reason to start a project so I can learn more! I would love to have the information needed to create an extension but I cannot promise that it will be done in the near future. But if you would like to give me the information needed, I would be honored :)

Comment: Excellent. Chase me down on IRC (aquarius) and I'll be happy to chat this over with you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know opera does have its own mechanism for sync, or do you need Ubuntu One specific and opera's own is not acceptable choice for you?

Comment: the reason I use ubuntu-one contacts is that I don't want to use different services or use different locations for my contact library. So that is why it would be great if my favourite browser could import the contacts from my ubuntu-one account.

Comment: The Idea behind DesktopCouch is to have a common Interface for basically any kind of information. For example bookmarks. Write an addon for Firefox, Chromium, Opera and IE and you have everywhere the same bookmarks. Same with Contacts, Calendar, Notes. 

Or think about RSS Feeds. I hate to read RSS Feeds with local readers, because every read feed appears unread on another PC. And Google Reader is not a good option